# How to access current placeholder value?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Symfony 3.4.
I have annotations for my controller:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/{prefix}", requirements={"prefix":"daily_task|event"})
 */
class TaskController extends Controller
```

and want to access current {prefix} value directly from controller's methods (which aren't routed actions). How to get it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally: $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->get('prefix')

Comment: I don't understand what this code is for, but if it is relevant to your question, you should edit the question body and put it there. If it is the solution which you found on your own, add some context to it, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony will pass you the variables automatically if you use them as function parameters, like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/{prefix}", requirements={"prefix":"daily_task|event"})
 */
class TaskController extends Controller {
  /**
   * @Route("/{_locale}/some/path", name="_some_route_name")
   */
  public function actualAction($prefix, $_locale) { /* ... */  }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use the whole request like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/{prefix}", requirements={"prefix":"daily_task|event"})
 */
class TaskController extends Controller {
  /**
   * @Route("/{_locale}/some/path", name="_some_route_name")
   */
  public function actualAction(Request $request) { 
     $prefix = $request->get('prefix');
  }
}
```

Comment: Request and parameters injection works only for action methods - that was the problem.